# Adding Custom View to XML Layout with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-view

I've been working on an app where a ball (bitmap) appears on the canvas at the point where the user taps on the screen. The background is an xml layout setContentView(R.layout.newsession). The canvas is a black painted canvas. When i set my java parent class setContentView(customView), the program works fine but when I add the custom surface view to my XML layout and setContentView(R.layout.newsession), the screen just shows the canvas, and the OnTouch event doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? I've been working on this for almost a week now and I really need help. I will post my code below for the XML layout and custom surfaceView. Thanks in advance!

XML layout (newsession)

```
    <FrameLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/newSessionPage" 
    >   

    <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="231dp" 
      android:id="@+id/ivStrikeGrid" 
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:layout_height="270dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="18dp" 
      android:src="@drawable/strike_grid"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

    <appsys.studios.CustomSurfaceViewOne 
     android:id="@+id/customSurfaceViewOne1" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"></appsys.studios.CustomSurfaceViewOne
    >

  </FrameLayout>
```

Custom SurfaceView

```
   package appsys.studios;
   public class CustomSurfaceViewOne extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
       public CustomSurfaceViewOne(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
          super(context, attr);
          ourHolder = getHolder();
     }
      // Other stuff
  }
```

It works fine like this:

```
    newSeshView = new CustomSurfaceViewOne(this, null);
    setContentView(newSeshView);
```

But nothing happens when I try to use it from the XML layout, like this:

```
    newSeshView = new CustomSurfaceViewOne(this, null);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsession);
```

Thanks again! :)

Comment: Did you make a copy paste error? I don't see any code inflating the custom view from xml? As in: `CustomViewOne cvo = (CustomViewOne)findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewOne1)`

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm relatively new and I don't quite understand what I need to do. Am i supposed to do this in my parent java class or in my custom view class? I think i might be forgetting this and it's not working because of this. Could you please elaborate a little bit more? Also, don't i already have something that the custom view is equal to?

        newSeshView = new CustomSurfaceViewOne(this, null);

Comment: Well, in your last code snippet you say you're trying to use your custom view from xml. However, that snippet is identical to the one above and shows a programmatical instantiation of your view. If you're seeking to use the view declared in your xml file, you should inflate your view from it. That means that somewhere in an `onCreate()` you will have to do `setContentView(R.layout.newsession);` and after that you can do CustomViewOne cvo = (CustomViewOne)findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewOne1) to get your custom view declared in the xml layout file.

Comment: Right that was just a typo mistake with the identical parts. I fixed that and now the last part of my code is setContentView(R.layout.newsession). I tried what you said and the new 'cvo' variable gave an error saying that it wasn't being used at all. So I don't see how that being there would help me.

Comment: Alright, that looks slightly better, altough I still don't see how you're inflating your custom view from the xml file. What happens if you add `newSeshView =  (CustomViewOne) findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewOne1)` *after* `setContentView(R.layout.newsession);` and remove the instantiation that is currently there. If you're still getting stuck, take a look at the [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) example that illustrates the use of a custom view from a declarative layout.

Comment: Alright I tried what you said and changed the code to this        "setContentView(R.layout.newsession);
  newSeshView = (CustomSurfaceViewOne) findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewOne1);"     and i removed the code saying "newSeshView = new CustomSurfaceViewOne(this, null);" but it gave me an error when launching the app, saying "The application Pitch Tracker Pro (process appsys.studios) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: That error message can be about literally anything. You will need to look up the specific error in [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) (if you're in Eclipse, you may find enabling [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) handy). For another example that inflates a custom View, but more specific to your case (extending a custom SurfaceView), please have a look at this [blog post](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/another-exercise-of-surfaceview-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing  **invallidate()**  call of the view on its touch reading delegates.

I am not sure exactly what is happening in your code. But if i would be creating my own view and adding it in my own layout as you did.
And want it to change itself on reading touch events then i would be doing something like
in the myown view class it self

```
   @override
    // i dont remem exact signature of this method. google it or see docs
    // motive is to read touch event of view and doing appropriate changes
    // and redrawing the view again
   public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
   {
      doCalculation(); // change points where to draw the ball next time. Read me
      invalidate();  // tell the view re draw it self

   }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't really understand what you're trying to say. And i tried  adding invallidate(); to the end of my OnTouchEvent but it comes up with an error "The method invallidate() is undefined for the type NewSesh"

Comment: Spelling mistake type invalidate() .   And also verify your view class is a subclass of default View or any of its subclass

Comment: It's still giving me an error when i try invalidate(); saying that it isn't defined in my java class. And what do you mean 'verify your view class is a subclass of default View or any of its subclass'?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and found your question while looking for the answer. I solved it, but I'm not sure it is the proper way.

3 files, your main activity, your surfaceview, and your XML file.

Your XML file looks ok, you have the surfaceview in it

```
<appsys.studios.CustomSurfaceViewOne 
 android:id="@+id/customSurfaceViewOne1" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"></appsys.studios.CustomSurfaceViewOne
>
```

In your activity, add `implements OnTouchListener`, use `setContentView(R.layout.newsession);` and after that, still in your `onCreate()` add this line `CustomViewOne cvo = (CustomViewOne)findViewById(R.id.customSurfaceViewOne1)` and set the listener to it by `cvo.setOnTouchListener(this);`

then add your onTouch

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    customSurfaceViewOne1.myOnTouch(event);
    return false;
}
```

where `myOnTouch()` is a method in your customSurfaceViewOne1 class where you will do all your ontTouch events. Notice I passed in the `MotionEvent event`.

Again, I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, it's just how I got it to work. The reason I did it was just so I could have an admob ad above my surfaceview lol.